# How to calculate Due Fees?

Tags: php

I want to calculate due fees, w.r.t current month. All session of schools starts from Apr, and fees starts from Apr.

If student not pay any fees in Apr, May, Jun, and now paying fees in Aug. Than Due fees must be Apr + May + Jun.

But I`m confused how to get due fees based on current month.

My code:

```
$current_month = date('M');
$final = 0;
for($i='Apr'; $i<$current_month; $i++)
{
$query_run = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT amount FROM fees_on_class WHERE class = '$class'");

while ($num = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($query_run)) 
{
    $temp += $num['amount'];
}

$final = $final + $temp;
}
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT into dues(registration_number, due_fees)VALUES('$registration_number','$final')");
```

Code is not working and giving Zero (0).

Thanks.

Comment: Does your table has a column which mentions when was the last month a student paid the fee?

Comment: @Akshay No Actually.

Comment: How would you calculate fees due if you don't even know when was the last time a student paid his fee?

Comment: @Akshay, Firstly student when admitted they commonly not pay fees. Say admission was in Apr. But they pay first fees in Aug. Than due fees would be sum of apr, may and june fees.

Comment: And when would they pay after August?

Comment: In Aug, their sum of fees is Due Fees + Aug Fees. Say if total is 4000, they pay, 2500. Than now due fees is updating and become 1500. Hope you getting me.

Comment: Your model is not correct and writing a good code for this model is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Alphabetic value in for loop you are using will not work as you want.

```
for($i='Apr'; $i<$current_month; $i++)
{
}
```

Please make month loop numeric.

```
for($i='4'; $i<$current_month; $i++)
{
}
```

I have not checked the whole code, but this is the first error I can see..

Comment: We don’t have access to run and debug your code also we don’t have idea about your database schema. So, debug the code yourself. If you have any specific error let us know.

Comment: have you made $current_month = date('M'); to $current_month = date('m');